# Calculating heterogeneity of groups within a sample

Tags: group-differences, heterogeneity

I am currently trying to find the proper statistics measure to calculate the heterogeneity of a group of students. The problem is the following:

I have a population of students, divided into groups of 5/6 students. Each student has 2 grades. I am trying to calculate how heterogeneous/homogeneous each group is. I try the coef. of variance using the grand mean, but I am not sure if that might be the best way, or should I use a value representing the most homogeneous case instead. Is there any unitless statistic measure that can give me an indication and that permit knowing across groups which are more heterogenous than others? (bearing in mind that groups might differ in size).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the intended purpose of this?  There cannot be a unique general answer to such a broad question, so we need to know more about your context and objectives.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The objective is to know how each group is heterogeneous with regard to grades and a homogeneous group will be that students have similar grades, while heterogenous means there are good students with bad students. The goal is that given a set of groups, we need to have a common measure of heterogeneity so we can compare groups with regards to heterogeneity.

Comment: Once you decide what an appropriate measure of heterogeneity might be for your purposes, you can compare (*via* division) the heterogeneity of any subgroup to the heterogeneity of the collection of all students. That will be unitless by construction.  Often people use the variance for this measure for its nice mathematical properties, but it's always worth considering whether that's suitable for your purposes and types of data. Also, there is always the option of re-expressing the data first. It can be helpful to express grades in a way that makes their overall distribution nearly symmetric.